# How do you fill imageview to screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="galleryimages.galleryimages.Main2Activity"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/linear1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:ignore="InvalidId" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: I tried filling the screen but as you can see,the borders are black.How to fill full image?im new to android]

i want the images to fill the whole screen. And should i write separate code for 18:9 ratio mobiles? Also,if i delete an image, it's not syncing with google photos.

Comment: Given you don't want to have black, I would suggest adding `android:scaleType="centerCrop" `.  This will fit the image so it fills the screen.  Using an image that reflects the aspect ratio of the phone will result in less cropping.  Using fitXY will result in deforming the image from its original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute to the ImageView:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: I tried them.It works fine for some images .If the image is a horizontal image then the picture is zoomed

Comment: *i want the images to fill the whole screen* this is what you wanted

Comment: Then post another question and explain what you want exactly providing all the code or images that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use from this code:

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

and other way:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            int ratio = imgTop.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() / imgTop.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
            int newheght = width / ratio;
            imgTop.getLayoutParams().height = newheght;
```

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me. Add it in the ImageView attribute:

```
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you must add below code:

```
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

in xml file